# Unity Resource.Load sprite returning null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resources, sprite

Ok, I've beat my head against a wall on this enough... As the title says, Resource.Load("icons_3"); is returning null. Ive cut back on as much as I can with the code to figure it out (simplifying it). Heres what I have

```
icon.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(items[i].item.itemIcon);
```

Pretty simple. The itemIcon is "icons_3"
This is coming out of a sprite that is set as multiple (a sprite sheet sliced up). I can drag the sprite manually onto the object, but that defeats the purpose.
The sprite sheet is in the Assets/Resources/ directory, so it should load off just the name. Originally it was in the Resources/Sprites folder, but to cut back everything, I moved it up a directory. 
So im at a total loss with this one. Is it because its a sprite sheet? Do I need to use another method to load a sprite from a sprite sheet? Thanks for all the help in advance guys.

Comment: Just to leverage off an old solution, what happens if you load the sprite into a variable first? `var loadSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("icons_3");`

Comment: just comes back null as well.

Comment: I am not even sure if Resources.Load() Uses Generic Type Casting before hand. Have you tried Resources.Load("icons_3")  as Sprite; ?

Comment: var sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Grass50x50");

Comment: Yes, it uses generic type casting. I have tried both methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick test just to make sure.

```
void Start()
{
    SpriteRenderer sr = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    sr.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/BlueBlock");
}
```

The Sprite sits in `Assets/Misc/Resources/Sprites/`.

Works just fine, so I guess you made an mistake somewhere else.

This must be done:

- Your Sprite must be set to texture type `Sprite (2D and UI)`.
  This will create a "sub-sprite" in the Sprite (with the Sprite Editor) by         default at least if it is a single sprite. The name of this might differ from the main sprite if it is multiple, so make sure you have that right. Make sure that the whole path you give to the Load is correct (case sensitive as fare as I know).

EDIT:

For a sprite that is set to multiple and is sliced you need to use `Resources.LoadAll`. Those sprites have a name property though which you can use for searching in a loop. Alternatively you can create a Dictionary (with string being the name) or more complex also a sprite atlas.

Comment: No, I dont think I've made a mistake anywhere. The problem I think lies with the sprite being part of a sprite sheet. I have switched over and used LoadAll then using a list with some linq to sort through and find the sprite im looking for.

Comment: That should not be a problem. If you use the sprite editor to "sub sprite" a sprite sheet, you obviously need to take the name you gave the sub sprite  to get the correct one. Sounds to me that you referred to the sprite sheet directly.

Comment: That was my thought as well. I even tried naming it directly, didnt work. For some reason, the only way to address the sprite is by loading the entire sheet, then I can find it by name.

Comment: I will try a sprite sheet later, when I'm at home. Don't have access to unity right now.

Comment: Ok, seems like it is not possible to use Load() for a multiple sprite. Did a little edit on how to work around that.